# How to apply a properties of navigation bar item to multiple view controllers at once?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I want to apply some properties Like navTitle,font,left-align title in Navigation Bar to every navigation controller. so I was wondering if there was a way to do this instead of writing multiple line of code in every controller? I want to call below function in every controller.
Anyone know how to do this?

```
func setLeftAlignedNavigationItemTitle(text: String)
      {
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = text
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 18)!, 
          NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  class NavigationTitle {


      static var shared: NavigationTitle = NavigationTitle()

      private init() {}

      func setLeftAlignedNavigationItemTitle(text: String)
      {
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = text
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 18)!, 
          NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
       }

}
```

Than you can call this method in every other class with this : `NavigationTitle.shared.setLeftAlignedNavigationItemTitle("Hello")`